# Can arc length be negative?

Tags: calculus, curves

I have a quick question that has been bothering me since I took my calc 2 final earlier. The question dealt with arc length and was pretty much plug and chug using the the arc length formula. My concern is my final answer left me with a negative length with didn't seem right to me, but I couldn't figure out any place where I went wrong.

> Is a negative arc length a possible answer?

Comment: Sorry, I think arc length can be negative depending on which direction you travel around the curve.

Comment: No.  Arc length is always positive.  Perhaps your integration limits got flipped.

Answer (score 4):

The *arc length* of a curve cannot be negative, just as the distance between two points cannot be negative. But one can use the usual arc length formula to define an *arc length parameterization* of a curve, and this parameter can take on negative values (just as one can talk about negative *displacements* in some coordinate system.)

(The above prohibitions do not hold, by the way, for "indefinite signature metrics", like the Lorentzian spacetimes of general relativity.)

Comment: Thanks that's what I figured. I want to say the function I was given was f(x)=sqrt(x) evaluated from 0 to 1. The one sure thing I remember is after I computed everything I got .25-.5

Comment: Im pretty sure I got lost somewhere with the derivative being raised to power of 2.

Comment: @Travis: "_The above prohibitions do not hold for "indefinite signature metrics", like the Lorentzian spacetimes of general relativity._" -- This seems intuitive by looking at the signs of spacetime intervals. However, I've struggled to find or establish a formal expression of this. Standard arc length would have to be replaced by $$\int_{\gamma}~\text{d}t~\text{sgn}[~g[~\gamma', \gamma'~]~]~\sqrt{|[~g[~\gamma', \gamma'~]~]|};$$ and the word "_distance_" (or "metric") might be substituted by [a suitable generalization (my suggestion: "**hypometric**")](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699360).

Comment: My comment about the indefinite case was a hedge to exclude exactly the issue you mention. For that same reason, in the indefinite case it's often better to work with the quantity $\langle \gamma', \gamma' \rangle$ that a signed square root (informally the "length-squared", though it need not be positive), just as it's often better to work with $X \cdot Y$ instead of the angle between $X$ and $Y$, as the usual definition (of angle) runs into trouble when $X$ or $Y$ is isotropic.

Comment: Travis: "_in the indefinite case it's often better to work with the quantity $\langle \gamma', \gamma' \rangle$ tha[n] a signed square root (informally the "length-squared", though it need not be positive)_" -- Could you please tell me the formal, "technical" name of this quantity $\langle \gamma', \gamma' \rangle$, and perhaps sketch how "_to work with_ it" when considering arc length? (I know about [Lorentzian distance](https://www.google.de/#q=%22lorentzian+distance+function%22); but that's of definite sign, of course.)

Comment: Travis: "_often better to work with $X \cdot Y$ [...] as the usual definition (of angle) runs into trouble when $X$ or $Y$ is isotropic_" -- Which sort of objects $X, Y$ do you mean there? p.s. Since you've been mentioning "_the usual definition (of angle)_": Considering three events $A, P, Q$ in flat spacetime with $$s^2[~A,P~] > 0,~~~s^2[~A,Q~] < 0,~~~s^2[~P,Q~] = 0,$$ then $$\frac{(2~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~A,Q~] + 2~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~P,Q~] + 2~s^2[~A,Q~]~s^2[~P,Q~] - (s^2[~A,P~])^2 - (s^2[~A,Q~])^2 - (s^2[~P,Q~])^2)}{(4~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~A,Q~])} \ge 1;$$ thus, it seems, indefinite arcs are not smooth.

Comment: I don't know know a shorter name for that quantity that "the inner product of $\gamma'$ with itself" (but N.B. the some people reserve 'inner product' for definite bilinear forms). My comment about "how to work with it" was informal---what I really mean is that in practice one generally doesn't work with the square root of this quantity. As for smoothness, I don't quite understand your argument, but note that smoothness of a curve doesn't depend on a metric structure (and hence doesn't depend on whether a curve is isotropic), it just depends on a smooth structure.

Comment: Travis: "_people reserve 'inner product' for definite bilinear forms_" -- Aha. (Unfortunately I'm not well-versed in such terminology conventions. [Apparently, any metric tensor $g : T \times T \rightarrow \mathbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) is a [dot product (a.k.a. inner product)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product); but perhaps this doesn't apply to pseudo-metric tensors.)

Comment: Travis: "_your argument_" --$$\text{Sin}[~\angle PAQ~] :=$$ $$\left( \frac{(2~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~A,Q~]+2~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~P,Q~]+2~s^2[~A,Q~]~s^2[~P,Q~]-(s^2[~A,P~])^2-(s^2[~A,Q~])^2-(s^2[~P,Q~])^2)}{(4~s^2[~A,P~]~s^2[~A,Q~])} \right).$$(Recall [Heron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) and "[trignometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_trigonometry)".) "_smoothness of a curve doesn't depend on a metric structure_" -- But surely **a notion of "smoothness" can be defined** from metric structure; or its generalizations. (And I care about what's compatible with that.)

Answer (score 1):

The arc length formula is:  $s $ $\displaystyle = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right)^2} \operatorname d x
\\[1ex] \displaystyle = - \int_b^a \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right)^2} \operatorname d x$

So whether you get a positive or negative result depends on the bounds.  There's no guarantee that $a<b$ will give a positive measure.

And similar for the polar coordinate, or parameter vector versions.

Comment: The argument of the square root should be $1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ (not with a $-$ as written); in particular the integrand is always positive, so if $a < b$ the quantity $s$ *is* always positive.